# Call functions with varying parameters to modify a numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I want to eliminate the unefficient for loop from this code

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((5,5))

for i in range(5):
    x[i] = np.random.choice(i+1, 5)
```

While maintaining the output given

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2. 1. 0.]
 [1. 2. 3. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 3. 3. 1.]]
```

I have tried this

```
i = np.arange(5)
x[i] = np.random.choice(i+1, 5)
```

But it outputs

```
[[0. 1. 1. 3. 3.]
 [0. 1. 1. 3. 3.]
 [0. 1. 1. 3. 3.]
 [0. 1. 1. 3. 3.]
 [0. 1. 1. 3. 3.]]
```

Is it possible to remove the loop? If not, which is the most efficient way to proceed for a big array and a lot of repetitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a random int array with the highest number per row as the number of columns. Hence, we can use `np.random.randint` with its `high` arg set as the no. of cols. Then, perform modulus operation to set across each row a different limit defined by the row number. Thus, we would have a vectorized implementation like so -

```
def create_rand_limited_per_row(m,n):
    s = np.arange(1,m+1)
    return np.random.randint(low=0,high=n,size=(m,n))%s[:,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: create_rand_limited_per_row(m=5,n=5)
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]])
```

To leverage [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data -

```
import numexpr as ne

def create_rand_limited_per_row_numepxr(m,n):
    s = np.arange(1,m+1)[:,None]
    a = np.random.randint(0,n,(m,n))
    return ne.evaluate('a%s')
```

#### Benchmarking

```
# Original approach
def create_rand_limited_per_row_loopy(m,n):
    x = np.empty((m,n),dtype=int)
    for i in range(m):
        x[i] = np.random.choice(i+1, n)
    return x
```

Timings on `1k x 1k` data -

```
In [71]: %timeit create_rand_limited_per_row_loopy(m=1000,n=1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit create_rand_limited_per_row(m=1000,n=1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop

In [73]: %timeit create_rand_limited_per_row_numepxr(m=1000,n=1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.98 ms per loop
```